# ROC-AUC in GEE models?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, roc, auc, generalized-estimating-equations

I am wondering if it is possible to make ROC-AUC curves for GEE models? I found few papers who did that and it wasn't clear for me. I thought it was impossible given how they are marginal models. Would someone give me their opinion and how to proceed about producing a curve if possible?

Comment: Isn’t GEE a method for estimating the parameters of a generalized linear model, such as a logistic or probit regression, rather than a model itself? Once you have the estimated regression coefficients, it seems like you should be able to make predictions and use those predictions to draw ROC curves like you would for any other predictions. // Could you please give references for this being done? The nuances of previous work might be important.

Answer (score 0):

Generalized estimating equations (GEE) are a technique for estimating parameters. GEE is not a model on its own, much as maximum likelihood estimation is not a model.

Thus, the way to create ROC curves for models estimated with GEE is the same as the usual approach:

1. Decide on a model (such as a logistic regression)
2. Estimate the model parameters from the data, using GEE as the estimation approach (instead of an alternative estimation method like maximum likelihood or minimization of the sum of squares)
3. Make predictions using the fitted model
4. Calculate the sensitivity and specificity at many thresholds

That final step will be handled by standard software packages if you pass in the true and predicted outcomes, such as `pROC::roc` in `R`.